# Google Sheet importxml create table from xml file

Tags: xml, google-sheets, xml-parsing, google-sheets-formula, xpath-1.0

Trying to use importxml in google-sheets. My XML file is something like this:

```
<file>
<file_name>file1</file_name>
<file_id>407897</file_id>
<disk_id>180622</disk_id>
</file>
```

There are tons of files in this xml ~5k.
I'm trying to have a table in a google-sheet like this below:

```
col 1 | col 2 | col 3
file1 | 001   | 001
file2 | 002   | 002
```

Now sometimes file doesn't have a disk id so it would be:

```
  <files>
    <file>
    <file_name>file1</file_name>
    <file_id>1</file_id>
    <disk_id>1</disk_id>
    </file>
    <file>
    <file_name>file2</file_name>
    <file_id>2</file_id>
    </file>
    <file>
    <file_name>file3</file_name>
    <file_id>3</file_id>
    <disk_id>1</disk_id>
    </file>
<files>
```

Table I want to create would something like this:

```
col 1 | col 2 | col 3
file1 | 001   | 001
file2 | 002   | 
file2 | 002   | 001
```

I tried using:

```
=importxml("url","//file_name | //file_id | //disk_id")
```

This gave me something like this (single column):

```
file1
001
001
file2
002
file3
003
001
```

and adding transpose it gave something like this:

```
=transpose(importxml("url","//file_name | //file_id | //disk_id"))

file1 001 001 file2 002 file3 003 001
```

Is there any way to get this using importxml in google-sheets?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: sorry I don't have one. The real file is huge and has some private data .. I was simplifying the case trying to get some help.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close to reaching your goal. You only need to modify the [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) in the [`IMPORTXML`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342) formula to read rows instead of attributes. Based on your example XML, you want something like this:

```
=IMPORTXML("{XML URL}","/FILES//FILE")
```